# Find minimum of max function $f:\mathbb{R^+}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ f(x_1,x_2) = max\{1-\sqrt{x_1}, |x_2|\}$

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Is there any closed-form way of finding it using gradient and Hessian? I tried branching my function into

$2f(x_1,x_2) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1-\sqrt{x_1}\ - x_2\ + |1 - \sqrt{x_1} + x_2|, \ x_2 \le 0 \\
      1-\sqrt{x_1}\ + x_2\ + |1 - \sqrt{x_1} - x_2|, \ x_2 > 0
\end{array} 
\right.$

and find the subdifferential

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2)=0 \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0,\ x_2 \le 0 \\
      1,\ x_2 > 0
\end{array} 
\right.$

but plotting the function seems to show something completely different
[image]

Comment: You are missing a crucial point of information: On what domain is the function defined? Also, the occurance of absolute values makes this problem probably not so well suited to standard calculus methods, IMO.

Comment: Right, sorry, edited the title accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x_1,x_2) \geq |x_2| \geq 0$ and $f(1,0)=0$ so the minimum value is 0.